# Improve recursive algorithm

Tags: java, performance, list, recursion

**EDIT:**
So I have this recursive code which "scrambles" numbers on a list and calls a method to check if the order in which they are "solves" one x requirement listed below.

```
for(int e=0;e<nums.size();e++){
    int v = nums.remove(e); //Takes the number from nums
    solucion.add(v); //Adds it to the solution

    if(solve(nums, solution))return true; //Calls solve recursively

    solution.removeLast(); //Removes the element added to the solution
    nums.add(e,v); //Places the number on its original position 
}
```

This piece of code is inside a method called solve which looks like this:

nums is the list of numbers read from the console. solution starts as an empty list.
This code works great but it's REALLY slow. Is there any way you think I can improve this piece of code ?

If it helps, the requirement is to check if there's a way to organize numbers and create a magic square from them (columns sum is the same as rows sum and diagonals sum)